# Spring Boot ObjectFactory Performance Cost

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance

I work on a team where every little bit of performance on our application is critical. We're working on migrating from Java to spring boot and there are several instances where we'd need a `ObjectFactory<?>` to handle the dependency injection of required beans.

I wrote a simple test where we create an object 1 million times using new and 1 million times using spring `ObjectFactory<?>.get()`. I was seeing a huge difference in performance from this where the pure java version took **0.06 seconds** and then the spring version took **23+ seconds**.

**Test Files**

*main*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    @Autowired
    ObjectFactory<Employee> employeeObjectFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startSpringless();
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println(employees.size());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void start(){
        var startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            var employee = employeeObjectFactory.getObject();
            employee.goToWork();
            employees.add(employee);
        }
        double totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println("Spring seconds: " +totalTime/1000);
    }

    public static void startSpringless(){
        var startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            var employee = new Employee(new Car(), new Clothes());
            employee.goToWork();
            employees.add(employee);
        }
        double totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println("No Spring seconds: " +totalTime/1000);
    }
}
```

*Employee*

```
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Component
public class Employee {

    private final Car car;
    private final Clothes clothes;

    @Autowired
    public Employee(Car car, Clothes clothes) {
        this.car = car;
        this.clothes = clothes;
    }

    public void goToWork(){
    }
}
```

*Car and Clothes*

```
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Component
public class Car {
}

@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Component
public class Clothes {
}
```

Is there anyway to create prototype beans that is more peformant? Or is my performance test not working how I expect it is?

Comment: That "benchmark" looks fishy for several reasons: 1) JVM warmup 2) order of benchmarked methods 3) dead code elimination; all of which could affect your results. Add all your employees to a list and print its size at the end of the loop – the results could be totally different.
But Spring might as well apply a lot of additional logic to beans, e.g. autowiring dependencies and bean postprocessing.

Comment: @knittl dead code elimination definitely was playing a role. Made the recommended changes and that did slow down the pure Java version but not by much. It completes in ~.06s

Comment: Just create a `Supplier<Car>` bean, inject it and let that create your instances?

Comment: @daniu similar performance unfortunately

Comment: The question I'd ask myself: do you need _Spring beans_ or can you live with regular objects created by a regular factory? Do you need all that dynamic autowiring, post-processing, proxying, etc.?

Comment: @knittl yeah I think this is the question. I think we'll need to engineer things in a way to avoid prototype beans since it's not performant

Comment: @andresmonc not everything needs to be a bean. You can use regular object instances with Spring just fine. Beans are managed by Spring, but if you don't need that, creating regular instances is the way to go.